# Should I use jigit to save bandwidth when downloading daily CD images?

Tags: iso, downloads

I thought I'd start having a look at 12.04. Since the image is going to change a lot in the near future, I thought it would be wise to use jigit. As I recall, it only downloads things that have changed since the last time?

I installed the package "jigit". Now what? It doesn't provide a jigit command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't an answer how to use jigit, but I think you're using the wrong tool for the job here.

jigdo (and it's associated tools like jigit) is useful to people who have an Ubuntu mirror handy and want to assemble an ISO out of that archive. I've done this and it's kind of annoying, it's more a tool for people who run archives and want to make it available to jigdo users.

It sounds like you want to save bandwidth and so you don't have to redownload things in the ISO. The end user tool you want to use for that is zsync. In the ISO directory of ubuntu releases (and mirrors) you will find a .zsync file that you can use to keep your ISO up to date. You use it like this:

```
zsync http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/daily/current/precise-alternate-amd64.iso.zsync
```

Will keep an up to date ISO of the alternate installer for precise for you. The next day you just run that again and it will sync just the differences between the 2 ISOs.

The testing tool [testdrive](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/testdrive-cli) is a convenient tool for testing development releases in a VM; it has built in support for zsync downloading. You can use testdrive to make getting the ISOs easier.

It has downloading functionality built in, which will ask you which ISO you want and then keep an updated copy for you in `~/.cache/testdrive/iso`, and the [GTK gui](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/testdrive-gtk) will automatically notify you when new ISOs are available or you can just use the command line version.

Comment: In the [daily image page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/daily/current/) I see both `.jigdo` and `.zsync` files, so I guess you can use any of them if you like. This [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4875/12596) can be useful for further information about both tools.

Comment: Your answer was very much correct. It was my answer that was wrong. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad Perhaps reword your title to be something more like what you want just in case someone really wants to know how to actually use jigit and wants to ask that question. (That will make it easier for people to find in the future too)

Answer (score 4):

If you install the `jigit` package, it should provide the `jigit` command, which you can use in accordance with the instructions on the [`jigit` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/jigit.1.html). This is a reasonable way to create an Ubuntu `.iso` image when you already have many of the package files that go into it, which would ordinarily only be the case (starting out) if you were running the same release that you're trying to make an `.iso` for.

You should probably not use `jigit` for testing Precise, for two reasons:

1. Part of what's valuable about testing is to test is the specific, [official daily-live `.iso` images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) that have been created. These eventually lead to the numbered alpha and beta images and ultimately to the release image, so testing them specifically is good.
2. There is already a mechanism in place for avoiding excessive downloading of duplicate data. The daily-live `.iso` images support [`zsync`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/zsync.1.html). For example, if you want the Precise i386 daily-live `.iso` image, you can run:
   `zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/precise-desktop-i386.iso.zsync`
   The first time you run that, it will just download the whole thing. Subsequent runs will download only what is necessary to bring the `.iso` image you have up to the latest `.iso` image that has been released.
   You should be aware that while the daily-live is the latest Precise image most of the time, it is not the latest all of the time. When a numbered alpha or beta release has just come out, it is the latest, and daily-lives are often suspended for several days following such a release, so it is important to use the numbered alpha or beta whenever there is no daily-live that is more recent. If the numbered alpha or beta image has a `.zsync` file of its own then you could rename the daily-live `.iso` you have so its name is the same as the numbered alpha or beta `.iso`, then zync up to the numbered alpha or beta `.iso`. Otherwise (or if you want to even further reduce load on Ubuntu servers), you could just get the numbered alpha or beta image by torrent.

Answer (score 2):

I have only been able to find just slight documentation on the use of jigit. [Jigit Section of Ubuntu 11.04 Guidebook](http://books.google.com/books?id=CS7txn0x8OEC&lpg=PA49&dq=using%20jigit%20application&pg=PA49#v=onepage&q=using%20jigit%20application&f=false). There's also a little community documentation on jigdo found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JigdoDownloadHowto). It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but might be enough to get you started in the right direction.

Comment: In summary, you need to install `jigdo-file` package and use `jigdo-lite` command (`jigit` package seems to contain tools to create the images, not to download them).